# WPF DataTrigger on UserControl Not Working

Tags: xaml, triggers, blend, datatrigger

My project is WPF (Windows Presentation foundation) with the 4.5 framework using Visual Studio 2012.

I have a UserControl in my window which I'd like to animate(move) automatically after input has been entered into a textbox.

Here is the usercontrol...

```
<nbcuc:Search x:Name="search" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <nbcuc:Search.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </nbcuc:Search.RenderTransform>
        <nbcuc:Search.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SearchAnimationState, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="New">
                        <Setter Property="nbcuc:Search.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardSearch}" />
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </nbcuc:Search.Style>
    </nbcuc:Search>
```

I know the Storyboard animation works because I had it working on the Window.Load event trigger.  I want a property to be set to something and then fire the trigger.  I know the property it working because I set the value to a textbox in my window.

I'm rather new to wpf and xaml so this really makes little sense to me why it would not work.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try replacing BeginStoryboard with ConstrolStoryboardAction to Play your target storyboard instead?

Comment: I'm not seeing ControlStoryboardAction as valid markup if I replace BeginStoryboard with ControlStoryboardAction.

Comment: I must be thinking in SL terms then. Will re-examine the question a bit later today when I have more time. Cheers :)